# Can't get leafletjs maps to work with Meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, leaflet

Trying to learn Meteor, using their Parties example. I added leafletjs code example to test maps, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am not even getting any errors. Here is the parties example, which work in a normal html page. Is this because of Handlebars? Would be great if anyone knows any issues. Thanks.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>

  <title>Wishes</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  {{> page}}

  <div id="wishmap" style="height:400px;"></div>

  <script>
    var mapa = L.map('wishmap').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/28cc49f16f1747ebae3100fb3d32f05a/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(mapa);

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate template for your map-

```
<template name="myWishmap">
  {{#constant}}
    <div id="wishmap" style="height:400px;"></div>
  {{/constant}}
</template>
```

Then track when that template is rendered - to call your javascript

```
Template.myWishmap.created = function(){
  Template.myWishmap.rendered = _.once(function(){
    var mapa = L.map('wishmap').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/28cc49f16f1747ebae3100fb3d32f05a/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(mapa);
  });
}
```

Then add to your `body` tag, as normal:

```
{{> myWishmap}}
```

You wont need the `{{#constant}}` block, and the created-rendered-once hack once the new Meteor templating engine is released (Meteor 1.0)

Comment: Thanks @NathanM. But if the map is in the create-rendered-once block how can I make use of reactiveness of Meteor. This way the map is working but, any updates to the map are not propagated to all the other browsers with this map.

Comment: If your data is in a collection, published to the client. You can set up an `Collection.observe`, in that same hook, which monitors for new items `added`, `changed` or `removed`. In the calllbacks, you'd add or remove the markers as required. - I've built a reactive canvas, and a reactive calendar this way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one could also use - Atmosphere Meteor Package Control to install the leaflet maps package.

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/leaflet

Many other package are already developed and available on Atmosphere.